# How to get all rows from DB using hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, antlr

This code works fine, returning single row:

```
public static Customer GetCustomerFromDB() {

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(com.english.Customer.class);
    configuration.configure();

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Customer customer = session.get(Customer.class, 1);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    sessionFactory.close();
    return customer;
}
```

I need all rows from DB, from table customer. Table customer contains one element. Small change. Remove session.get() and add these lines:

```
//same code as above
CriteriaQuery<Customer> criteriaQuery = session.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Customer.class);
criteriaQuery.from(Customer.class);

List<Customer> contacts = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
Customer customer = contacts.get(0);
//same code
```

Error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/RecognitionException

POM:

```
//...
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/antlr/antlr -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>3.0ea8</version>
        </dependency>
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this to get all the rows:

```
String hql = "FROM Customer";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List results = query.list();
```